# Understanding SP.clientContext.executeQueryAsync and the order that it pulls data

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sharepoint

I have a function that loops through a comma-separated list of email addresses.
Within the loop, we pass some parameters (including the email address) to a 'getUserProperties' function that uses SP.clientContext.

I have stripped back the code within the function to:

```
getUserProperties = function (targetUser, userCount, parentCtrl) {
var deferred = $.Deferred();
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);
var userProfileProperties;
var profilePropertyNames = ["PictureURL", "PreferredName", "SPS-JobTitle", "Department", "WorkPhone", "WorkEmail", "PersonalSpace"];
var userProfilePropertiesForUser = new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(
    clientContext,
    targetUser,
    profilePropertyNames);
userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertiesFor(userProfilePropertiesForUser);

console.log(userProfileProperties);
console.log(userProfilePropertiesForUser);

clientContext.load(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {

    console.log(userProfileProperties);

},function (sender, args) {
   deferred.reject(null);
});

return deferred.promise();
```

}

My issue in terms of understanding what is going on is that the first **console.log(userProfileProperties);** displays the data requested to the console log in the same order as in the previous loop function.

This is the same as the **console.log(userProfilePropertiesForUser);** call.

However, once the **clientContext.load** and **clientContext.executeQueryAsync** are called and then the **console.log(userProfileProperties);** is displayed for the second time the order of the data is different to that in the loop from the previous function.

Thus I would like to know why the data is different to that which is passed into the function, as the **clientContext.load** and **clientContext.executeQueryAsync** appear to be affecting it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first log just output a JavaScript object declaration, the user profile didn't populated yet until you call `clientContext.load` and `clientContext.executeQueryAsync` .

Check below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[one thread for your reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108819/difference-in-clientcontext-load-and-clientcontext-executequeryasync-in-java)

Comment: Thanks Lee_MSFT, I see about no user data being populated until the call on `clientContext.load` and `clientContext.executeQueryAsync`. I am still struggling to work out the order the call is made.

Imagine in my (parent) function I have a string with the value of 'lee1@e.com,lee2@e.com,lee3@e.com'. I turn the string into an array & loop through  array a call the getUserProperties function. I thought the order in which `clientContext.load` and `clientContext.executeQueryAsync` work would be the order of the emails in the string, as these are 2 separate functions but the orders don't match